# Populating a 2d int array int[][] a certain number of times

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a battleship game where I place certain ships based on certain sizes. For some reason my method that i'm placing the ships isn't working.

For reference the code with the 2 methods (thought i'd paste the whole class since it only has 2 important methods which i'm on about)

```
public class Board {

    public static final int ID_EMPTY = 0;
public static final int ID_BATTLESHIP = 1;
public static final int ID_AIRCRAFT_CARRIER = 2;
public static final int ID_DESTORYER_1 = 3;
public static final int ID_DESTORYER_2 = 4;
public static final int ID_PT_BOAT = 5;

private static final int ROW_COUNT = 10;
private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = 10;

private static final int SHIPS_PER_FLEET = 5;

private Ship[] fleet;
private int[][] gridCells;

private Random randomizer = new Random();


public Board() {

     this.fleet = new Ship[SHIPS_PER_FLEET];
     this.gridCells = new int[ROW_COUNT][COLUMN_COUNT];
     // Fill the grid cells with OPEN WATER -1s.
        int i = 0;
        while (i < ROW_COUNT) {
            int j = 0;
            while (j < COLUMN_COUNT) {
                this.gridCells[i][j] = Ship.openWater;
                j++;
            }

            i++;
        }

  }

/*
 * add a ship to the grid.
 */
    public  void placeShips(Ship newShip){
             int row = newShip.getRow();
                int column = newShip.getColumn();
                int orientation = newShip.getOrientation();
                int i = 0;

                // Add the ship to the fleet array.
                this.fleet[newShip.getshipType()] = newShip;

                if (orientation == Ship.orientationUp) {
                    while (i < newShip.getShipLenght()) {
                        this.gridCells[row - i][column] = newShip.getshipType();
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else if (orientation == Ship.orientationRight) {
                    while (i < newShip.getShipLenght()) {
                        this.gridCells[row][column + i] = newShip.getshipType();
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else if (orientation == Ship.orientationDown) {
                    while (i < newShip.getShipLenght()) {
                        this.gridCells[row + i][column] = newShip.getshipType();
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Orientation must be LEFT. Only one left =]
                    while (i < newShip.getShipLenght()) {
                        this.gridCells[row][column - i] = newShip.getshipType();
                        i++;
                    }
                }

    }
public void placeShipsRandomly(){


        int [] shipType = {Ship.aircraftCarrier,
            Ship.battleship,
            Ship.Destoryer_1,
            Ship.Destoryer_2,
            Ship.PtBoat};

        int[] shipLength = {5, 4, 3, 3, 2};

             int i = 0;

                do {
                    int row;
                    int col;
                    int orientation;

                    // Randomly generate a row, column, and orientation.

                    row = randomizer.nextInt(ROW_COUNT);
                    col = randomizer.nextInt(COLUMN_COUNT);
                    orientation = randomizer.nextInt(4);


                    boolean bFitsOnBoard = false;

                    // Check to see if the ship fits on the board at the given row and column.

                    int testLength = shipLength[i] -1;

                    if (orientation == Ship.orientationUp) {
                        if (row >= testLength) {
                            bFitsOnBoard = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (orientation == Ship.orientationRight) {
                        if (COLUMN_COUNT - col > testLength) {
                            bFitsOnBoard = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (orientation == Ship.orientationDown) {
                        if (row - ROW_COUNT > testLength) {
                            bFitsOnBoard = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (orientation == Ship.orientationLeft) {
                        if (col >= testLength) {
                            bFitsOnBoard = true;
                        }

                    boolean bHitsOtherShips = false;

                    // Check to see if the ship hits any other ships on the board.

                    if (bFitsOnBoard == true) {
                        int j;
                        if (orientation == Ship.orientationUp) {
                            j = 0;
                            while (j < shipLength[i]) {
                                if (this.gridCells[row - j][col] != Ship.openWater) {
                                    bHitsOtherShips = true;
                                    break;
                                }

                                j++;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (orientation == Ship.orientationRight) {
                            j = 0;
                            while (j < shipLength[i]) {
                                if (this.gridCells[row][col + j] != Ship.openWater) {
                                    bHitsOtherShips = true;
                                    break;
                                }

                                j++;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (orientation == Ship.orientationDown) {
                            j = 0;
                            while (j < shipLength[i]) {
                                if (this.gridCells[row + j][col] != Ship.openWater) {
                                    bHitsOtherShips = true;
                                    break;
                                }

                                j++;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (orientation == Ship.orientationLeft) {
                            j = 0;
                            while (j < shipLength[i]) {
                                if (this.gridCells[row][col - j] != Ship.openWater) {
                                    bHitsOtherShips = true;
                                    break;
                                }

                                j++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ((bFitsOnBoard == true) && (bHitsOtherShips == false)) {
                             // Place this ship on the board.
                        Ship newShip = new Ship(shipType[i], orientation, row, col, shipLength[i]);

                        this.placeShips(newShip);

                        // Go on to the next ship.
                        i++;
                            }
                    }
            }
                while (i < SHIPS_PER_FLEET);
}
    /*
     * returns the grid cell
     */
    public int[][] getGridCell()
    {
   return this.gridCells;
    }


}
```

It has 2 problems.

The main problem is that on certain runs of the program it is creating an out of bounds error and trying to place a ship on row 10 which doesn't exist because the array of int[10][10] only goes up to 9 ofcourse since they start at 0 etc.

The second problem is i'm trying to place ships based on their size however it seems to be placing all ships and giving them all the ships of size 3.

So for example lets say this is the array output.

```
[0] [0] [3] [3] [3] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [4] [0] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [4] [0] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [4] [0] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [1] [1] [1] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [2] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [2] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [2] [0]
```

That's wrong because i've made the length of the ships int[] shipLength = {5, 4, 3, 3, 2};

So based on which cycle it's going through on the placeships method it should be placing the ship with a different size each time, other than the 3rd and the 4th ship which are both deystroyers and have the same size.

I'm having a brain freeze and can't figure out what's going on, can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Paste your code here for future reference.  Links will die over time, making the content here useless to future readers.  Also, you have only pasted 1 of the critical methods - can we see the second one as well, to help debug the problem?

Comment: I forgot to include the whole class for where the problem was, i've edited the question to include it. The class I pasted in the above comment is the class that's linked in. @torquestomp. Also edited the question properly and as per previous request input the code into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two simple errors, that I can see:

```
else if (orientation == Ship.orientationLeft) {
    if (col >= testLength) {
        bFitsOnBoard = true;
    }
// ED: Where's the '}'?

boolean bHitsOtherShips = false;

// Check to see if the ship hits any other ships on the board.
```

There is no brace here to close the else if - your code is not doing what you think it is doing.  Only ships that randomly roll orientation == Ship.orientationLeft are actually making it to the collision test, and then potentially being placed.

Secondly, your Ship() constructor (which should NOT be in an external link buried in the comments!), has this signature:

```
public Ship(int shipType, int shipLength, int row, int column, int orientation) {
```

But, when you declare your new Ships for placement:

```
Ship newShip = new Ship(shipType[i], orientation, row, col, shipLength[i]);
```

The orientation and shipLength variables are swapped!  Since only ships with orientation type Ship.orientationLeft are being instantiated, and since Ship.orientationLeft = 3, all the ships being drawn are of length 3.

As for the index out of bounds, that's easy.  Since you're submitting the shipLength as the orientation, none of your boundary checks earlier in the code mean anything, and an out-of-range case can happen easily.

Comment: I wish I had done this 2 hours earlier. I was trying something completely different to overcome this. I really appreciate your help, honestly.